# Can't get correct div positions with jQuery .unload() and .position() in Firefox

Tags: jquery, html

I'm using the `unload` event to save the positions of `draggable` divs to `localStorage`

This seems to work well with the browsers who support both the `unload` event and HTML5 Web Storage, except for Firefox (13.0 beta).

In Firefox the unload event fires as expected when refreshing the page and gets all the top and left positions of the divs correctly. But when the unload event is triggered by closing the tab, all the positions are returned as 0.

Anyone know why? Am I better to use `onbeforeunload` maybe?

You can test it with this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/fhfXh/8/.

Comment: Since you're going to save the positions on every unload anyway, would it be an acceptable solution to save the position to localstorage on each `dragstop` event instead?